# .NetCore Project after publish on iis get 404 for all subroots

Tags: iis, .net-core, routes, publish

I publish dotnet core 2.2 project on iis server.
but all subroots of website get 404 errors, all apis and views
i set .net core clr version to no managed code but nothing changed

Comment: First you can try publishing a fresh new template project targeting same framework version so you will be sure if the reason is on your project configuration or iss configuration.

Comment: published version of project work fine in host with direct admin. problem happen just when it is in iis server

Comment: Do you mean you could access the views on the root? If you couldn't access it, I suggest you could re-check you have installed the right asp.net core runtime. If you have installed and could access root view. I suggest you could post the IIS folder structure and asp.net core root path settings in the startup.cs.